# How do I get my grounding up to code? Subpanel is missing grounding connector

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

I have a bit of a situation with my interior subpanel not being grounded properly.

The interior subpanel does not receive a ground wire from the main service panel where it is grounded (to the water pipes where it enters the house), but it does have a ground wire attached to a seperate location on the pipe, and hence having that pipe act as it's ground path back to neutral at the panel. I'm wanting to install a surge protector at the subpanel, and this all seems a bit sketchy to me as that means that any surges would travel through the pipe, possibly electrifying them.

Would my proposed solution (in dotted line) be code legal and effective? I'm not able to open the main panel to to run a new ground wire as the finishing makes it inaccessible, and would require removing the meter (which is of course locked down).

[image: Image of plan for attaching grounds together with main panel]
Thanks,

[image: panel]

[image: panel2]

Comment: A lot of unknowns here. Can you upload pictures of your panels?

Comment: The ground bond should be in your main panel and should be accessible (not blocked by your meter)

Comment: the main panel has no fasteners to get any of the covers off, so I'm assuming that whatever fasteners there are are under the meter. Also, since the main panel only has a single breaker, I feel uncomfortable with opening while the power is still on.

Comment: Just added pictures.

Comment: Added more pictures.

Comment: The main panel appears to have an access screw right down near the latch, in the normal location for a panel of that style.